# PHPUnit: My Package Class not found

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I am working on a package for Laravel 5 and my PHPUnit Tests are failing with **error**

> **"Class VendorName\PackageName\MyPackage not found"**

I still can't make out what is responsible for this error and would be glad if someone assists.

This is what my structure looks like:

```
src/
    ├─ MyPackage.php
test/
    ├─ MyPackageTest.php
composer.json
composer.lock
```

**Composer.json**

```
"psr-4": {
    "VendorName\\PackageName\\": "src/"
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "VendorName\\PackageName\\Test\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

This is (possibly) where my error is coming from:

**MyPackageTest.php**

```
namespace VendorName\PackageName\Test;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use VendorName\PackageName\MyPackage;

class MyPackageTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $app;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->app = new MyPackage();
    }
}
```

**Here's my phpunit.xml file**

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.5/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         covertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>
         <testsuites>
           <testsuite name="Interswitch Test Suite">
             <directory suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
           </testsuite>
         </testsuites>
  </phpunit>
```

I have done the usual `composer dump-autoload` rituals to get this working as it should but all to no avail.

I also changed the `composer.json` file in the root of my Laravel project with the content above but I still could not get this to work.

Comment: try to require your vendor autoload file or bootstrap it in phpunit.xml file.

Comment: @Follio I did that already `bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"`

Comment: Add require provider and aliases in app.php

Comment: @Komal Definitely did this to get package to work generally in the first place. Currently stuck with PHPUnit Test.

Answer (score 0):

Could not reproduce. Works perfectly well for me with following composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
       "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.5"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4": {
            "VendorName\\PackageName\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

and phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.5/phpunit.xsd"
    bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php">

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">test</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Weird. I still have this issue.

Comment: I just included `phpunit.xml` configuration in my original post. Would be glad if you could help me check whether I'm on track or not.

Comment: Are you sure you are **using** this file? I mean do you run your tests as `vendor/bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml` ? Does your vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php  contain "'VendorName\\PackageName\\' => array($baseDir . '/src')" ? Are you using exact names, or something different (names are case-sensitive)?

Comment: Finally got this problem solved! I checked my `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4`.  It turned out to be a conflict with laravel's composer.json file as I previously dumped my package namespace on that file and I was dumping Test namepspace on my package's composer.json. I have corrected and PHPUnit assertions are Green now :D. Many Thanks Alex.